# Visualforce charting mouseover hint are not displaying properly

Tags: visualforce, charts, visualforce-charting

Hi today while working found that visualforce charts were acting weird when there is a big text included in the display/hover field. The hover text was not properly displaying the value and the content.

Here is the code to replicate the same.

```
<apex:page >
    <script>
        // Build the chart data array in JavaScript
        var dataArray = new Array();
        dataArray.push({'name':'Category 1','Amount':66});
        dataArray.push({'name':' Big Category','Amount':100});
        console.log(dataArray);

    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:chart width="450" height="400" data="dataArray">
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Category"/>
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Amount" title="Amount"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="bottom" 
                xField="name" yField="Amount"/>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And the screenshot of the issue : [image: Visualforce Charting Hover Bug]

Any Idea how to fix this one?

Comment: Have you tried this in different browsers AND do the browsers have different default font size settings?? The latter could potentially affect this problem. E.G. Large Fonts could cause overflow or wrapping. Depending on the browser, the box may or may not expand to accommodate.

Comment: Tried this using chrome.. And I guess this will be the browser we are going to use

Answer (score 3):

Try **chartTips width**

```
<apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
```

[image]

In your sample:

```
<apex:page >
    <script>
        // Build the chart data array in JavaScript
        var dataArray = new Array();
        dataArray.push({'name':'Category 1','Amount':66});
        dataArray.push({'name':' Big Category','Amount':100});
        console.log(dataArray);

    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:chart width="450px" height="400" data="dataArray">
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Category"/>
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Amount" title="Amount" />

            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="bottom" 
                xField="name" yField="Amount" >
                <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
            </apex:barSeries>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the tooltip box via implementing apex:chartTips.renderFn Javascript method.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartTips.htm#kanchor1120

Comment: Why whole function if height and width attributes might be just enough?